# How to avoid duplicated React when using Github repository as dependency

Tags: reactjs, npm, hyperlink, dependencies

I'm running multiple React projects that share several UI components. To keep them consistent and minimize the efforts to maintain, I created a mutual repository and use it as a dependency. Other projects will install this repo dependency and import components from it.

```
dependencies": {
    repo: git+ssh://git@github.com:YourName/repo.git
}
```

For pure UI components in `repo`, everything works fine. But as I created a component that uses React Hooks to manage its own state, an error happened saying that I might have more than one copy of React in the same app (one belongs to the main app and one belongs to the dependency).

The same issue when you use `npm link`, which I found a few workaround as described [here](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991). However, I couldn't make it work with a Github dependency.

Has anyone tried something similar and found a way to tackle this issue?

Comment: Your re usable component repo has to mark React as peer dependencies, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58256291/1641941) will help

Comment: Thanks. I tried to register `react` and `react-dom` as `peerDependencies` for `repo` but it didn't work either.